# TWebBrowser Handle close request

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

I am using TWebBrowser with a class helper that introduces some new functions (in case this is relevant to the problem below):

```
type
  TWebBrowserEx = class helper for TWebBrowser
  public
    procedure Clear;
    procedure Wait;
    function LoadHTML(const HTML: string; const AFakeURL: string=''): boolean;
  end;
```

I noticed that if a JavaScript wants to close the browser window, the handle of TWebBrowser gets destroyed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.close();
</script>
```

Calling TWebBrowser.LoadHTML() etc. will result in an Exception.

I would like to decide what my application does when the JavaScript wants to close the window.
(My idea is, based on a configuration setting, either clear the page and let the application stay open, or close the application).

Question: How do I handle this?
My first guess was to receive the WM_DESTROY message, but I think it doesn't work with class helpers, because nothing happens.

```
type
  TWebBrowserEx = class helper for TWebBrowser
  private
    procedure MessageDestroy(var msg: TMessage); message WM_DESTROY; // <-- will never be called
  public
    procedure Clear;
    procedure Wait;
    function LoadHTML(const HTML: string; const AFakeURL: string=''): boolean;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign the `OnWindowClosing` handler of your `TWebBrowser` to something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1WindowClosing(
    ASender: TObject;
    IsChildWindow: WordBool;
    var Cancel: WordBool
);
begin
    Cancel := True;
end;
```

This will not spawn a "Do you want to close the window?" dialog and simply discard the JavaScript request to close the window.

Comment: Thank you so much for this hint. I overlooked that event, as I was looking for "OnClose"! Such a simple and nice solution.